# No rule to make target 'localmodconfig'

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, make

I'm trying to build and install a new kernel version in

> Lubuntu version 5.11.0-38-generic

using this tutorial

- Get your system ready

  `sudo apt update`

  `sudo apt-get install build-essential vim git cscope libncurses-dev libssl-dev bison flex libelf-dev bc git-email -y`
- Clone a mainline kernel source code to your computer:

  `git clone --depth=1 \https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git`
- To save time, just create a configuration file based on the list of modules currently loaded on your system (choose default values for other options).

  `lsmod > /tmp/my-lsmod`

  `make LSMOD=/tmp/my-lsmod localmodconfig`
- Disable certificate stuff:

  `scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS`

  `scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS`
- Compile the kernel.

  `make -j3 all`
- Install the new kernel:

  `sudo make modules_install install`
- Now it is time to reboot the system to boot the newly installed kernel:

  `sudo shutdown -r now`
- Show your new current kernel version:

  `uname -r`

But when I use this command `make LSMOD=/tmp/my-lsmod localmodconfig` it show an error `make: *** No rule to make target 'localmodconfig'.  Stop.`
What is the meaning of this error? Are there any ways to find where this error come and fix it?

Comment: What release of Lubuntu are you asking about?  You only gave the kernel version; not release details.

Comment: @guiverc It is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (focal). Thank you. Turn out I need to cd to a directory where has Makefile so I can use make command.